# Why is the constructor for my class not being called in this case?

Tags: c++

I am creating a new class instance like this:

```
Cube* cube1;
```

There is code in the `Cube` constructor, but it's not being run! Is this usual?

Comment: Find a good tutorial on C++, you're lacking a very important basic notion : the difference between pointers and objects.

Comment: This is not a game development question and probably belongs on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're actually not creating any instance.

the variable you're calling `cube1` is a pointer to a `Cube`.

To create a Cube you should have:

```
Cube* cube1 = new Cube();
```

This create a new instance of Cube in heap memory, you should call `delete cube1` once you don't use it anymore.

or:

```
Cube cube1;
```

This create a new instance of Cube in stack memory, it will be destroyed once it goes out of scope.

PS. you should get a C++ textbook.

Comment: I did think this, but the strange thing is I can call functions on the pointer without it being instantiated. Clearly another misunderstanding, but can you clarify?

Comment: The compiler doesn't check to see if the pointer is actually pointing at anything, because in most cases it's impossible for it to know. The programmer must make sure to avoid using the pointer before it has been assigned to a legitimate object.

Comment: Kylotan is right, you created a valid (from a type pov) Cube pointer. But this pointer isn't pointing to any valid object. From the compiler's pov everything is OK, but at runtime it fails as there's no actual Cube.

Answer (score 1):

You're not creating an instance of a Cube; you're creating a pointer to a Cube.

To create a pointer to a new instance of a Cube, you'd want code like this:

`Cube* cube1 = new Cube;`